# Need the name of a series of books on colonization from 1980s

Tags: story-identification

This is a long shot, I know, but I was hoping someone knew the name of a series that started, I believe, in the 1980s.

All I remember is that it was a colony ship that was sabotaged, and the chief engineer's girlfriend was killed; but he was able to incorporate her personality into the ship. Oh, and her name was Grace.

I know that's not much, but any help would be appreciated. It's been bugging me for years!!

THANKS!!!